# How do I get all entities of an App Engine model class, including those of its subclasses?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, subclass

I've got a question about Google App Engine and querying the datastore.

Suppose I've got three classes:

```
class Animal(db.Model):
   age = db.IntegerProperty()

class Giraffe(Animal):
   # ...

class Mouse(Animal):
   # ...
```

Now I want to get all the Animal entities. I might try

```
Animal.all()
```

But that doesn't return anything (I created all the Animal entities using the Giraffe and Mouse constructors).

How do I get all the Animal entities? Is the general approach (subclasses of a subclass of db.Modell) ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Engine doesn't directly support class inheritance, but there's an extension built into the SDK called [PolyModel](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/polymodelclass.html) that does. Modify your Animal class to extend PolyModel instead of Model, and everything will work the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The datastore doesn't keep track of inheritances like this.  Each Entity has a single "kind".

If you wanted all of the animals to be of the same kind, you could have a property that indicates which sort of animal (Giraffe or Mouse) it is.  So, you'd make each new entity an `Animal`, but then set the "type" property or whatever to Giraffe or Mouse.  You lose some of the nice features of inheritance this way, which is a drag.

Comment: Aw, thanks. The problem is that I need to interact with the Giraffe in a different way than I do with the Mouse, and they have different properties. Do you know the recommended way to do this? I can think of a) storing the data as a string property (e.g. Animal.specialInfo = "Species:Mouse, Favorite_brand_of_cheese: xyz") or b) using a list that references the individual subclasses (I might create an AnimalCollection).

Comment: You could keep your current setup, and just change your query - instead of Animal.all(), call Giraffe.all() and Mouse.all() and combine those results in a list of generic `Animal`s.

Comment: The problem with that is that I need to adjust the list generation code for every new class that I have. But I guess I'll do that if I don't find a better solution.